# how implement method Scheduler.interrupt to stop a Job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

i've no idea how implement this method of the interface InterruptableJob i don't know if the best way to stop a job is with this method or using deleteJob is better, the problem is that with deleteJob the job stops completely and i just need that only that execution stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer as I don't have the rep to comment yet, but what version of quartz?  It's concept of pausing and stopping differ between versions...

OK, as per the comments below, a patch I remember coming into our project (Ikasan) in order to get around this was something along the lines of not using the `scheduler.pauseJobGroup(jobGroup)` but instead looping over each job and calling `scheduler.pauseJob(JOB_NAME, jobGroup)`

Likewise we then used `resumeJob` as opposed to `resumeJobGroup`

I'll try to dig up the exact code from our commit history - we bundle our own quartz when working with Jboss now.  There have been a lot of fixes :)

Comment: i'm using the quartz-server called quart-ra wich is a rar of the jboss 4.2. the version of the quartz is the 1.6.0

Comment: Hmm that makes it more difficult.  OK, I'll edit my original answer with what I think I remember we had to do

Comment: hi @karianna and thanks for asking,  but i have a question i have understood, that the method pauseJob, only just do that, pause the job, i wanna kill the instance of the job, but the jobs continue launch in the next firetime. I think if i use pause, the only thing that can granted is htat the job stop the next launch. For that reason i really think that the method pause and resume don't work for me

Comment: I thought in your original question that you wanted to stop the job for one execution?  In that case the pause should do the trick (IIRC pause is effectively stop in 1.6.0).  Otherwise I think the deleteJob/rescheduleJob combination might do the trick for you.  As the 1.6.0 API is a little misleading I'd recommend upgrading to 1.8.3 and providing the quartz.jar with your application